# Laravel JWT Auth Apache Settings Conversion to Nginx

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, system-administration

I'm new to nginx:

How to create this rules in nginx.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: I dont think you do even need these for nginx. These made for Apache only to convince it to work with bearer header properly